# php code for storing data in the table where new data should appear on top row

Tags: php, html

I have MySQL database and web page which are linked. When I updated data on database, my web page is showing date and time wrong what should I do , also how to display data in rows and columns(Table format)

**Post / Display data**

```
<?php
include("dbconnection.php");

$DTN = $CNT->query("select * from smsinbox ORDER BY id DESC");  
$msg = $DTN->rowCount();

echo "<div width=\"auto\" align=\"center\">";
echo "Inbox: <b>$msg</b> text messages  <a style=\"background-color: #4CAF50;border:none;color: white;padding: 5px 11px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;font-size: 16px;\" href=\"$PHP_SELF\">Refresh</a> <br>";


if($msg > 0){ 

    echo "<table cellpadding=\"10\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"border-color: #666666;border-width: 1px;padding:5px;border: 0px solid #666666;\">"
    ."<tr style=\"text-align:center;font-weight: bold; background-color: #ebf4fb;\"><td>Id</td><td>Phone</td><td>Text</td><td>Time</td></tr>";

    while($row = $DTN->fetch()) {

        echo "<tr>"
        ."<td style=\"background-color:#efefef;\">$row[id]</td>"
        ."<td style=\"background-color:#efefef;\">$row[phone]</td>"
        ."<td style=\"background-color:#efefef;\">$row[text]</td>"
        ."<td style=\"background-color:#efefef;\">$row[date]</td>"
        ."</tr>";

    }

    echo "</form>"
    ."</table>"
    ."</div><br>"
    ."</td>"
    ."</table>";

} else { 
    echo "<br><br><div style=\"width:20%;background-color: #efefef;padding: 8px 36px;\">inbox is empty<div>";
}

echo "</div>";
?>
```

**Retrieving data**

```
<?php
include("dbconnection.php");


$token = $_REQUEST['token'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['from'];
$text = $_REQUEST['text'];

if (($phone == "") AND ($text == "")) {

    echo "";

} else {

    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO smsinbox (phone,text,date) VALUES (:phone,:text,:date)";
    $q = $CNT->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(
    array(
    ':phone'=>"$phone",
    ':text'=>"$text",
    ':date'=>"$date"
    )
    );  

}

?>
```

The above are php code files, one is for retrieving data and another is posting or displaying data on webpage

Comment: Assuming your ID is an auto-increment field `select * from smsinbox ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: `I need updated data should appear on 1st row of the table.` - suppose you have rows with `id`1,2,3,4,5 and you are editing row number 3. Now when you show the data, what do you want ?

Comment: About the time issue, read this: https://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/. Longstoryshort - you need to set your timezone.